# Laravel api http requests sequencing / queued on 2 clients with different browsers

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have this test code:

```
echo date('h:i:s', strtotime('now'));

sleep(2);

echo date('h:i:s', strtotime('now'));
```

And when i run it at two different browsers at the same time, the 2nd browser will wait 2 seconds before running. I read somewhere that maybe it has something to do with session lock file, but I'm not using any session. Help me i need to make my API accept simultaneous request.

Comment: it should wait 2 seconds because you've put `sleep(2)`. so in php until the whole file is generated  it doesn't output anything

Comment: what i meant to say is the requests are being queued. ex: when i refreshed the 2 browsers at the same time, the 2nd browser will wait for the first browser to finish before executing.

Comment: try with same browser, (use chrome incognito mode as new browser)

Comment: Still the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Check your php configuration, you may have set `MaxClients` to 1. If not, try to add `session_write_close()` to your script to prevent lock of session file.